# Sculpting brush alpha/texture resolution?

Tags: sculpting, dynamic-topology, resolution

Does the image resolution of a brush texture in sculpt mode determine the detail of the stroke?

I'm using a textured brush w/the anchored stroke method and the smaller the stroke, the lower the resolution. It seems unaffected by any dyntopo settings or relative distance. The source images are good sized PSD files with no artifacts. Is there some setting I'm missing?[image: smaller = lower rez]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can. However, that isn't your issue. In order for texture resolution to be a factor, you would need the edges created by the Dyntopo system to be shorter than the pixels of your texture. That way, there is enough detail in your mesh to create 'steps' between pixels. But as I said, that isn't your issue. From some testing I just did, it appears that using the anchored stroke type doesn't generate new detail. I'm not sure if that is intentional or not, but it seems that is the reason the detail isn't changing.

Comment: Interesting... very succinct explanation... thanks!

Comment: I actually just found that all out by testing that myself, so I learned something too!

Comment: Quick update: same limitations with the drag dot method, but using the space method with the texture as a stencil and dyntopo on works very well. Thanks again, put me on the right path.